# What's the difference between the empty sort, 'a::{}, and a sort of "type", 'a::type

Tags: isabelle

Below, the comments show the output for the `term` commands:

```
declare[[show_sorts]]

term "x"

(* "x::'a::{}" :: "'a::{}" *)

term "x::'a"

(* "x::'a::type" :: "'a::type" *)
```

In a section title about a type class, I'm using the phrase "nat to type", when what I mean is "nat to 'a" (which I don't use because words generally work better in titles).

I need to be succinct, but if I'm also reasonably, technically correct, that's even better.

**Update**: Here, I try and clarify what I was asking about. I think I was saying this:

I'm confused. The command `term "x"` shows that `x` is of type `'a`, and that `'a` is of sort `{}`. Especially with hindsight here, and in comparison to what I got for `term "x::'a"`, a sort of `{}` is not what I would expect for `'a`. Here, like many times, I look to the software for answers, and when it tells me `'a` for `x` has no sort, that makes me wonder.

So, I minimally give `x` the type `'a`, which results in `'a` as having sort `type`. This kind of answer makes sense to me. Not that `'a` has to have the sort `type`, but that `'a` should at least have a sort, though my original motivation was to assure myself that the `'a` in a type class is of sort `type`.

From Lars' answer, I am reminded that the type inference engine interprets a type as broadly as possible, so I assume that's at the core of this.

**Update 2**

From Lars' additional comment, it turns out, at least for me, that a key phrase in understanding `'a::{}` is "sort constraint", the "constraint" in "sort constraint" giving important meaning to `{}`.

Here's some source for anyone who's interested in studying the subtleties of the language of types and sorts:

```
declare [[show_sorts]]
thm "Pure.reflexive" (* ?x::?'a::{} == ?x [name "Pure.reflexive"] *)
thm "HOL.refl"       (* (?t::?'a::type) = ?t [name "HOL.refl"] *)

(* Pure.reflexive *)
theorem "(x::'a::type) == x"
  by(rule Pure.reflexive)

theorem "(x::prop) == x"
  by(rule Pure.reflexive)

theorem "(x::'a::{}) == x"
  by(rule Pure.reflexive)

(* HOL.refl *)    
theorem "(x::'a::type) = x"
  by(rule HOL.refl)   

theorem "(x::'a::{}) = x"
  by(rule HOL.refl)
(*ERROR: Type unification failed: Variable 'a::{} not of sort type*)

(* LINE 47 HOL.thy: where the use of "type" is defined. *)
setup {* Axclass.class_axiomatization (@{binding type}, []) *}
default_sort type
setup {* Object_Logic.add_base_sort @{sort type} *}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean be the last two paragraphs? I fear, I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: @lars, I added a little to try and clarify. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: While any type has a fixed sort, a type variable can have an arbitrary sort constraint: This limits the types this variable can be instantiated to. The empty sort still makes sense -- look for example at the theorem `Pure.reflexive` -- this theorem holds for all types, hence there is no sort constraint. On the other hand, `HOL.refl` only applies to HOL types, hence there is a sort constraint to `type`.

Comment: @Lars, thanks for the additional comment. There's lots more to understand, but "constraint" in "sort constraint" has turned on some light bulbs for what "{}" means in the context of a "sort".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sort is an intersection of type classes. Hence, the most general sort is the full sort, written `{}` (i.e., the empty intersection). If a sort consists only of a single class, the curly braces are omitted.

In Isabelle/HOL, `type` is the sort of HOL types (in contrast to the types of the logical framework, most notably the type `prop` of propositions. So, all the types you usually work with (`bool`, `nat`, `int`, pairs, lists, types defined with typedef or datatype) will have sort `type`.

This guarantees the separation between of the types of the object logic (e.g., HOL) and the logical framework (i.e., Isabelle/Pure): Operators of the logical framework can be used to compose HOL expressions, but cannot occur inside HOL expressions.

So, when working in Isabelle/HOL, you almost always want your expressions to have sort `type` and hence `type` is declared as *default sort*, which means that the type inference will use this instead of the empty sort if no additional constraints are given.

However, due to a shortcoming(?) of the type inference setup, there are some rare cases where type inference still infers the empty sort. This can yield to surprising errors.

Comment: Of course, "the empty sort" is actually *the full sort* --- it covers all possible types.

Comment: Type-inference sometimes produces a most general type that the user does not expect.  This happens elsewhere, too, not just for full sorts in expressions like ``f x`` without any constraints from the context.

Comment: I edited the answer to be more correct w.r.t. to the full sort.